# What is the proper regex for string between delimiter with newline

Tags: javascript, regex

what is the regex for capturing string inbetweeen delimiters with newline.

String is:

```
/* start \*/This is a test of regex
```

with new line and (special char)

```
asdsadasd/* end*/
```

Please suggest a regex which outputs :- ***This is a test of regex
with new line and (special char)

```
asdsadasd
```

i.e string between /* start */ and  /* end */.

```
Here **/* start */** and **/\* end */** are the **delimiters**.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will match what you're after:
`/\/\* start \*\/(.*?)\/\* end \*\//gs`

- The `\` and `*` need to be escaped as they're special characters in regex
- the `(.*?)` section tells it to capture the shortest possible match containing any characters
- the `gs` at the end tell it to support multiple matches (`g`) and that `.` should match new line characters (`s`)

Sample code:

```
const regex = /\/\* start \*\/(.*?)\/\* end \*\//gs;
const str = `/* start */This is a test of regex

with new line and (special char)

asdsadasd/* end */
assorted unmatched crap

/* start */another match/* end */

blah blah blah

/* start */another
multi
line
match
/* end */
`;

let match;
while ((match = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    console.log(`Found a match: ${match[0]}`);
    console.log('----------------------------------');
}
```

Comment: what is the /s along with g means.g is global match but what is "s" for i did not clearly get it.documentation says single line. Dot matches newline characters.can you please clarify this

Comment: it means exactly that!

By default the `.` will not match new lines. If you remove the `s` from the example above you'll notice that it will only match the 2nd result (ie the one with no line breaks) since the `(.+?)` portion no longer matches the new lines.

I also forgot to mention the `match[0]` shows the full match text, you can use `match[1]` instead to get the part you're actually interested in

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[^]*?`.

Example:

```js
var string = `/* start */This is a test of regex

with new line and (special char)

asdsadasd/* end */`;

var result = string.match(/\/\*\ start \*\/([^]*?)\/\* end \*\//);

console.log(result[1]);
```